# How to pass parameters to class that is using template

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I created class using template and I made the constructor require parameter. The problem is that I don't know how to pass parameter when I am creating the object. I looked up online but I couldn't find a solution so I hope someone here can help me. I am guessing it should look something like this:

Example code:

```
template<typename T>
class Example {
     Example(typename T) {
          std::cout<<"Passed"<<std::endl;
     }
}
```

Example for creating the object:

```
Example<int> object(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about the C++ [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates).

First, your constructor is `private` so it is not accessible. You need to make it `public`. Second, in constructor `Example(T value) {...}` `T` represents a type, not the value.

This will do the work:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Example {
public:
    Example(T value) {
        std::cout << "Passed " << value << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Now, you can create an object by doing `Example<int> object(1);` or letting the type to be automatically deduced from constructro call `Example object(1);`.

Comment: That's why I put the example for creating the object. I wasn't sure if that's how I can call it. Thanks